# How to use recode_factor in dplyr for recoding multiple factor values?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, recode

```
     countrycode event
1713         ESP 110mh
1009         NED    HJ
536          BLR    LJ
2882         FRA 1500m
509          EST    LJ
2449         BEL    PV
1022         EST    HJ
2530         USA    JT
2714         CUB    JT
1236         HUN  400m
238          BLR  100m
2518         USA    JT
1575         FRA 110mh
615          JPN    LJ
1144         GER    HJ
596          CAN    LJ
2477         HUN    JT
1046         GER    HJ
2501         FIN    DT
2176         KAZ    PV
```

I want to create a new factor vector in my data frame, `eventtype`, where:

Rows with `100m`, `400m`, `110mh`, `1500m` in the `event` variable become grouped as `Runs`; `DT`, `SP`, `JT` gets grouped as `Throws`; and `LJ`, `HJ`, `PV`, gets grouped as `Jumps`.

I can create a new vector value individually with something like `` df$eventtype <- recode_factor(df$event, `100m`="Running") `` works for one event, but I looked in the documentation and there isn't an easy way to convert multiple values in one function call.

Edit: of course if there is another function which serves my purposes better I will use that.

Comment: `dplyr`: look at `case_when` or in base R the `ifelse` statement. And you left out what `110mh` should be

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `...` argument of the `recode_factor` function can take any number of arguments...

```
library(dplyr)

df <- read.table(header = T, text = "
number countrycode event
1713         ESP 110mh
1009         NED    HJ
536          BLR    LJ
2882         FRA 1500m
509          EST    LJ
2449         BEL    PV
1022         EST    HJ
2530         USA    JT
2714         CUB    JT
1236         HUN  400m
238          BLR  100m
2518         USA    JT
1575         FRA 110mh
615          JPN    LJ
1144         GER    HJ
596          CAN    LJ
2477         HUN    JT
1046         GER    HJ
2501         FIN    DT
2176         KAZ    PV
")

df$eventtype <- recode_factor(df$event, `100m` = "Runs", `400m` = "Runs", 
                              `110mh` = "Runs", `1500m` = "Runs", 
                              DT = "Throws", SP = "Throws", JT = "Throws",
                              LJ = "Jumps", HJ = "Jumps", PV = "Jumps")

# or inside a mutate command
df %>% 
  mutate(eventtype = recode_factor(event, `100m` = "Runs", `400m` = "Runs", 
                                   `110mh` = "Runs", `1500m` = "Runs", 
                                   DT = "Throws", SP = "Throws", JT = "Throws",
                                   LJ = "Jumps", HJ = "Jumps", PV = "Jumps"))
```

Answer (score 1):

ifelse is what you need.  Here are some sample code as you don't have a reproducible example.

```
countycode = c("ESP", "HUN", "KAZ")
event = c("100m", "JT", "PV")
data = as.data.frame(cbind(countycode,event))

# generate the recode groups.
runs = c("100m", "400m", "1500m")
throws = c("JT", "SP")
jumps = c("HJ", "PV")

# add another column.
data$eventtype = ifelse(data$event %in% runs, "Runs", 
                        ifelse(data$event %in% throws, "Throws",
                              ifelse(data$event %in% jumps, "Jumps",
                                     NA)))
```

After runs:

```
> data
  countycode event eventtype
1        ESP  100m      Runs
2        HUN    JT    Throws
3        KAZ    PV     Jumps
```